# Convenient way to transform struct with Cow-fields to owned

Tags: rust

I have a struct defined like

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    field1: &'a str,
    field2: &'a str,
    field3: &'a u8,
    // ...
}
```

that I use for returning parsing results from an `mmap`ped file. For some successful parses, I want to store the results for later processing and for various reasons that processing will happen after the memory is released. I could do something like

```
struct OwnedFoo {
    field1: String,
    field2: String,
    field3: Vec<u8>,
    // ...
}
```

and manually converting all `Foo`s that I'm interested in into `OwnedFoos`. However I'm wondering if I could do something like:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    field1: Cow<'a, str>,
    field2: Cow<'a, str>,
    field3: Cow<'a, u8>,
    ...
}
```

instead and if there's any way to automatically make all the `Cow`s owned and erase the lifetime parameter. I haven't found anything in the library documentation that seems applicable.

Something like:

```
let a = Foo { ... };
let a_owned = a.into_owned();
// do stuff with a_owned that I can't do with a
```

Comment: In your example, what's the type of `a_owned`? Do you want it to be `Foo` too?

Comment: I would love for it to be a `Foo` with the lifetime parameter erased, but it's more the ergonomics of use that I'm interested in. i.e. to not have to define new types.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Building blocks:

- `Cow::into_owned` will return the owned version.
- `'static` is the lifetime of the program

Therefore we can write a utility function:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn into_owned<'a, B>(c: Cow<'a, B>) -> Cow<'static, B>
    where B: 'a + ToOwned + ?Sized
{
    Cow::Owned(c.into_owned())
}
```

You can expand this to `Foo<'a>` becoming `Foo<'static>` by simply applying the transformation on all fields.

Comment: Do you know if there's any way to define IntoOwned for Foo, so that foo.into_owned() would return a Foo<'static>?

Comment: @dnaq: Sure, you just need two implementations: `impl<'a> Borrow<Foo<'a>> for Foo<'static>`, and then `impl<'a> ToOwned for Foo<'a> { type Owned = Foo<'static>; }`

Comment: Seems like I can't add that implementation for `Borrow` because of conflicting trait bounds. I guess that the instantiation of `impl<'a> Borrow<Foo<'a>> for Foo<'static>` where 'a == 'static is the issue.