# Implementing ToOwned ('a -> 'static) for an enum containing Cow<'a, str> causes unmet lifetime requirement

Tags: rust

### Context

Playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=de1286b8bce0dfb840a5fc0b50df25ad

I was reading [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42155212/convenient-way-to-transform-struct-with-cow-fields-to-owned), which was saying you can convert a struct containing a `Cow` to have a `'static` lifetime. Based on that post, I then tried the following:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

enum S<'a> {
    A(Cow<'a, str>),
    B(i32)
}

impl ToOwned for S<'_> {
    type Owned = S<'static>;
    
    fn to_owned(&self) -> Self::Owned {
        match *self {
            S::A(s) => S::A(Cow::Owned(s.clone().into_owned())),
            S::B(i) => S::B(i)
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = S::A("a".into());
    let s = s.to_owned();
}
```

and got the following error

```
error: incompatible lifetime on type
   --> src/main.rs:9:18
    |
9   |     type Owned = S<'static>;
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^
    |
note: because this has an unmet lifetime requirement
note: the lifetime `'_` as defined here...
   --> src/main.rs:8:20
    |
8   | impl ToOwned for S<'_> {
    |                    ^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the static lifetime introduced by the compatible `impl`
```

### Questions

- How exactly are lifetimes coming into play here if I'm converting the `Cow` into the owned version?
- What's the right approach to getting this to work?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I need to do it to not move out of &self, and also based on the implementations I don't think it does allocate redundantly since clone is a no-op on `Borrowed` https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/borrow.rs.html#195 and into_owned is a no-op on `Owned` https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/borrow.rs.html#324

Comment: You're correct, my mistake. Though it can be `(*s).to_owned()`.

Comment: Consider the answer here for the circumstances where you would and could implement `ToOwned`: [Implement ToOwned for user-defined types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72105604/2189130)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You cannot implement `ToOwned` for that; use an inherent method.

---

[`ToOwned::Owned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html#associatedtype.Owned) has a bound:

```rust
type Owned: Borrow<Self>;
```

So we need `S<'static>` to impl `Borrow<S<'a>>` for any `'a`.

...except this impl cannot be written:

```rust
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::borrow::Borrow<S<'static>>` for type `S<'static>`
  --> src/main.rs:19:1
   |
19 | impl<'a> Borrow<S<'a>> for S<'static> {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
           - impl<T> Borrow<T> for T
             where T: ?Sized;
```

...because it conflicts with the blanket implementation [`Borrow<T> for T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/src/core/borrow.rs.html#234-238) where `'a` is `'static`.

The compiler error without this impl is an outcome of the fact that the compiler sees that *there is* an `impl<'a> Borrow<S<'a>> for S<'static>` (the abovementioned blanket implementation), it is just that it constrains `'a: 'static`. And so the compiler tries to prove `'a: 'static`, and fails. This is an example of the compiler being over-smart, causing a confusing error message.